# How do I set a stylesheet in Javascript depending on the subdomain?

Tags: javascript, css

Hi I'd like to switch stylesheets depending on the subdomain of the site URL

Pseudo example:

```
if variationA.mysite.com then
    Use stylesheetA.css
else If variationB.mysite.com then
    Use stylesheetB.css
else 
    Use stylesheetC.css
end if
```

Comment: Are you using a server side language, or is this just an HTML page?

Comment: Hi, Just HTML only Casey

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on the client side with javascript like this:

```
var subDomain = window.location.host.split('.')[0]; //pull the subdomain from the host
var cssUrl = 'stylesheetC.css';
if (subDomain == 'variationA') cssUrl = 'stylesheetA.css';
else if (subDomain == 'variationB') cssUrl = 'stylesheetB.css';
$('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+cssUrl+"'>");
```

However, it would make a lot more sense to do this server side if possible.

Comment: Great!  If this was helpful, can you mark my answer as accepted so that this question will show up as answered to anyone else searching for it?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png